# Fill html dropdown using array from database php

Tags: php, html, postgresql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to fill dropdown in html from code below.I have searched here other questions and tried but it is not working for me? Can anyone help me to find my mistake?

```
<form  id="data" class="form-geofence" role="form" method="post" action="geofencedata.php">
                <select name="category_id">
                    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                    <?php 
                        include_once'./connectionusers.php';
                        $result=pg_query("SELECT * FROM geofence;");
                        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="" ><?php echo $row["name"];?></option>
                    <?php 
                            }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

I have used same php code seperately and it shows the names

Comment: it does not shows any options.it should show names from my database table.And also I,have tried by setting value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your database connection is right, and the use below code

```
<form  id="data" class="form-geofence" role="form" method="post" action="geofencedata.php">
            <select name="category_id">
                <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                <?php 
                    include_once'./connectionusers.php';
                    $result=pg_query("SELECT value FROM geofence;");
                    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                     echo "<option value='".$row['value']."'>".$row['value']."</option>";
                       }
                ?>

            </select>
```

Comment: I found the mistake. i had saved the file in html .so i changed it to php

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  id="data" class="form-geofence" role="form" method="post" action="geofencedata.php">
                <select name="category_id">
                    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                    <?php 
                        include_once'./connectionusers.php';
                        $result=pg_query("SELECT * FROM geofence;");
                        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row["name"];?>" ><?php echo $row["name"];?></option>
                    <?php 
                            }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

you missed to echo the option value, that may be your problem.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work .Only single blank option is there.

Comment: then there is some issue with the data fetching from database, try printing the array of result, or remove the drop down and echo the `$row['name'];`

Comment: i tried and it didn't show any option from database.If i run php code in different file it shows the names

Comment: what the starange problem you are experiencing? If i run php code in different file it shows the names// what you mean by that

Comment: It means if i copy only the php code and then open in browser it will give me the names column of my database table as output

Answer (score 0):

```
function category_dropdown($selected=""){

    $open_tag=$close_tag=$option_tag=$selected_class="";
    $open_tag="<select name='category_id' id='category_id'>";
    $option_tag.="<option value="">--- Select ---</option>";
    $close_tag="</select>";


    include_once('./connectionusers.php');
    $result=pg_query("SELECT * FROM geofence;");
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
        $selected_class=($selected==$row["name"])?" selected='selected' ":"";
        $option_tag.="<option value='".$row["name"]."' ".$selected_class.">".$row["name"]."</option>";
    }
    return $open_tag.$option_tag.$close_tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind

```
<select name="case_type" style="width:250px">
<option>select</option>
<?php
$sql="select case_type_code,case_type_name from case_type_master where display='Y' 
                      order by case_type_name asc";
 foreach($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
 {
$casetypecode=$row['case_type_code'];
if($case_type == $casetypecode)
            {
print "<option  value=".$row['case_type_code']."selected>".$row['case_type_name']
      . "</option>";
            }
       else
            {
            print "<option value=".$row['case_type_code'].">"
             .$row['case_type_name']."</option>";
    }
  }
     ?>

     </select>
```

I am sure it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your corrected code You missed to print value.

```
<form  id="data" class="form-geofence" role="form" method="post" action="geofencedata.php">
            <select name="category_id">
                <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                <?php 
                    include_once'./connectionusers.php';
                    $result=pg_query("SELECT * FROM geofence;");
                    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
                <option value="echo $row["code"];" ><?php echo $row["name"];?></option>
                <?php 
                        }
                ?>
            </select>
```